# How to return "None" in Fsharp?

Tags: f#

It just returns some " ", but I need to return "none".

How can I do this ?

```
let cat(filenames: string list) : string option =
    try
        let b = filenames |> List.map (fun x -> (defaultArg (concat(x)) ""))
        Some (String.concat "" b)
    with  _ -> None
```

Comment: Could you add more context? The code you wrote seems to return `None` when something goes wrong but it's not clear what could go wrong there. What's the definition of `concat`?

Comment: module readNWrite

let concat(filename: string) : string option =
   try
      let a = System.IO.File.ReadAllText filename
      Some a
   with _ -> None

let cat(filenames: string list) : string option =
    try
      let b = filenames |> List.map (fun x -> (defaultArg (concat(x)) ""))
      Some (String.concat "" b)
    with _ -> None

Comment: concat is definded from the previous code

Answer (score 4):

It returns `some ""` because an empty list doesn't cause an exception. You need to match on an empty list and return None. I also am not sure the `List.map` aligns with the concat you're trying to do here, perhaps you meant `List.reduce` ? 
Something like this might work.

```
let cat filenames = 
   match filenames with
   | [] -> None
   | l -> l |> List.reduce (+) |> Some
```